# How to include/find the source and header files for LL-Drivers?

Tags: stm32

I have been using STM32G474, but if I look into the HAL driver folder structure I cannot find the files for LL-Drivers. I want to use LL functions in my code.

Looking forward to your quick suggestions.

BRs,

Waled

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEVN4.png)

[STM32G4 Hal and Low layer drivers, UM2570](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3kbD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [file in the official STM32CubeG4 repo](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeG4/blob/master/Drivers/STM32G4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32g4xx_ll_hrtim.h) on github.

Either you have an older version of the code on your local copy, or the file got deleted somehow. You should be all good by getting the current version of the whole repo.